# Django "Unknown column in having clause" when combining F and Count in an annotation

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I've come across an issue when annotating with a Count, F object and integer

```
class Task(models.Model):
    my_integer = models.IntegerField()

class User(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey("Task", related_name="users")


Task.objects.annotate(
    sum= 1 + F('my_integer') + Count('users')
).filter(
    sum= 10
).count()
```

> OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'bug_example_task.my_integer' in 'having clause'")

---

Surprisingly it works if I change the order of:

```
1 + F('my_integer') + Count('users')
```

to:

```
F('my_integer') + Count('users') + 1
```

But unfortunately I'm locked into the order (I gave a minimal example). The actual annotation I'm doing is similar to:

```
(my_variable/F('my_integer'))%Count('users')
```

Which can't be rearranged :(

It query also works:

- without the filter()
- without the count()
- normally on SQLite3

The table I'm performing the query on is a hefty hippopotamus so I can't afford to do any python level processing. I've tried segmenting it into different annotations, using a Case/When to catch any div 0 errors, as well as and moving the calculations to the filter() but to no avail.

Am I doing something wrong? should I open a ticket? Please help me mr internet.

Django: 1.9.6 - - 
MySql: 5.7.11 - - 
Python: 2.7.10 - - 
OSX: 10.11.4

Comment: Could it possibly be because you are using a reserved word 'integer' as an annotation and a column name?

Comment: integer is not a reserved word in python/django. The actual name i used was different, i was just using it as an example :P

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html

Comment: I updated integer to my_integer to avoid the confusion. Django should be quoting all field names in queries. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 2):

> you are using a python key word `integer` which Django does not allow : Read here for more about [field-name-restrictions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#field-name-restrictions)

I checked the raw query in both order cases but the aggregation is conserving the same order at the DB level :

`HAVING (1 + F('my_integer') + Count('users')) < 12`

I don't really have an idea why changing the order matters in this case, but I found that the error occurs when you try to use `.count()` after the aggreration, the same error will occure also if I try to use `.aggregate(Count('sum'))`. So I suggest using simply `len` despite it's not the optimized way but I hope it could be helpful for now:

```py
len(Task.objects.annotate(
    sum= 1 + F('my_integer') + Count('users')
).filter(
    sum= 10
))
```

Comment: I have updated the question with "integer" -> "my_integer" and am still facing the same issue

Comment: Thanks for confirming the strangeness! Due to the size of the table I can't use len() so I've reverted to a raw query, which makes my cry every night :'(. I think i'll submit a django ticket when i get around to it. Thanks again.

Comment: Keep this post up-to-date if you have any news ;) I'm really curious to know how this could be best solved.